# Selected element rotation in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to build my own lightbox using Jquery but I'm stuck on getting next image to show up. I know that my current build is not working because `$("element").next()` is always the same . I need to somehow make the selector a variable that rotates to the next element every time the button is pressed. how can I do this in Jquery? any other tips on wrong code are welcome too.

This is what I got so far:

```
(function( $ ) {

    $.fn.Jlight = function(options) {


    var settings = $.extend({
    // These are the defaults.
    shadowwidth: $(window).width(),
    shadowheight: $(document).height(),
    width: $(".Jimage-container img").width(),
    height: $(".Jimage-container img").height(),
    },options);

    var left = ($(window).width() - $(this).outerWidth()) / 6;
    var bot = $(window).height() /2
    var bottom = bot/2;
    var img = $("#showbox").find("img").attr("src");

    console.log(img);


    $(this).click(function(){
        console.log('clicked showbox');

        $(document).keyup(function(event){    
        var key = event.which;                
        switch(key) {
          case 37:
              console.log("pressed left");
              var Go = $("#showbox img").attr("class");
              $("#showbox img").prev(Go)
              if (Go == "img-responsive first"){
                var img = $("#showbox img:last").attr("src")
                $('#Jimg').attr("src", img);
              }
              else{
                  var img = $("#showbox img").prev("img").attr("src");
                  var Stop = $("#showbox img").prev("img").attr("class");
                  $('#Jimg').attr("src", img);

                  if (Stop == "img-responsive last"){
                    console.log("last!!!!"); 
                    var last = $("#showbox img").find(":first").attr("src");
                    /*$('#Jimg').attr("src", last);*/
                  }
              }
              console.log(last, img)
              break;

                    }   
        });

        $("<div class=\"jshadow\"></div>").appendTo( "body" ).css({"width" : ""+settings.shadowwidth+"", "height" : ""+settings.shadowheight+""}).animate({"opacity" : "0.8"}); /*setting shadow*/
        $("<div class='Jimage-containter'></div>").appendTo("body").animate({"opacity" : "1.0"}, function(){ 
            $("<img src="+img+" class='img-responsive' id='Jimg'></img>").appendTo(this);
        }); /*setting imagefield */
        $(".Jimage-containter").css({"width" : settings.width, "height" : settings.height, "left" : left, "bottom" : bottom})
        $(".jshadow").click(function(){ $(".Jimage-containter").animate({"opacity" : "0"}, function(){ $(".Jimage-containter").remove() }),$(this).animate({"opacity" : "0"}, function(){ $(this).remove( ".jshadow"), console.log('Goodbye!'); }) }); /*removing shadow*/
        $("#showbox").find("img").last().addClass("last");
        $("#showbox").find("img").first().addClass("first");
        });
    };

}( jQuery ));


$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#showbox').Jlight()
});
```

html:

```
<body>
<header></header>
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 drie">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 negen">

     <div class="object"></div>
     <div class="object2" id="showbox">
     <img src="images/home-background.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
     <img src="images/no-image.jpg" class="img-responsive"  />
     <img src="images/Koala.jpg" class="img-responsive"  />
     </div> 
     <div class="object3"></div> 
     <div class="div"></div> 



    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Could you create jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: I made a jsfiddle but It's not working in it. http://jsfiddle.net/D4mhK/

Comment: the images are still referring to relative address change them to absolute address in jsfiddler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the LightBox is fired, you should get a reference upfront to all of the images associated with the set of images to be displayed. Most LB plugins do this using the `rel` attribute.

Single image:

```
<a href="kitten.jpg" rel="lightbox">Kitten</a>
```

Several images:

```
<a href="kitten1.jpg" rel="lightbox['cats']">Kitten</a>
<a href="kitten2.jpg" rel="lightbox['cats']">Kitten</a>
<a href="kitten3.jpg" rel="lightbox['cats']">Kitten</a>
```

So, if you do something like this:

```
$("a").on("click", function(){
  var collection = this.rel,
      links = $("a[rel='" + collection + "']"),
      images = [];

  links.each(function(){
    images.push(this.href);
  });

  // Do LightBox stuff
});
```

Then you are no longer reliant on using `$("element").next()` as you can simply cycle backwards and forwards through the images array.